# Circular animation duration issue with UICircularProgressRing

Tags: ios, swift, animation, progress-bar, dispatch

I am using [this library](https://github.com/luispadron/UICircularProgressRing) to have some circular progress bar in my table view cell. It should be able to indicate the progress i get simultaneously from AWS S3 progress block.

This is the progress block to upload file(image, video) to s3 bucket:

```
progressBlock = {(task, progress) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
       cell.circularProgressView.setProgress(value: CGFloat(Float(progress.fractionCompleted)), animationDuration: 0, completion: nil)
       print("PROGRESSING \(Float(progress.fractionCompleted))")
       if(progress.fractionCompleted == 1.0)
       {
       }
    })
}
```

`progress.fractionCompleted` keeps updated in block, but it does not reflect on UI (cell.circularProgressView), and i set `animationDuration: 0` because i am not supposed to know when uploading might finish.

**Note:** I suspect, the loop in progressBlock stops the progress/animation, when it is hit for the first time, it animates, then it will stop forever.

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: check if progressBlock is executed in `MainThread` maybe that is the problem

Comment: Have you set any maxValue for your progress view?

Comment: it is background thread @ReinierMelian

Comment: @UmairAamir actually i have set maxValue, but it wasnt matching with the progress float max value. thanks for catching my focus. it fixed the problem :)